# a combined total of x and/or y

Tags: phrases

On a wiki a user has replaced all instances of the phrase

```
a combined total of 100 x and y
```

with

```
a combined total of 100 x or y
```

Which one is more correct/appropriate to use? Is it situational? Are they interchangeable?

Comment: What is x? What is y? And exactly what is being totaled? If you are simply adding the value of x to the value of y to get a total, it should be a combined total of x and y, but there are other possibilities...

Comment: @ScotM: I'm guessing **x** and **y** would have to be *numeric values*, since I can't really get my head around any context where you could reasonably use the text string *a combined total of apples and oranges* (or whatever other "countable" things they might be if they weren't numbers).

Comment: Two other possibilities: either x or y is a series of values that can be totaled separately. Fourth possibility: both x and y are a series of values that can be totaled separately. The word ***combined*** suggests the **fourth** possibility, but with a value of one, nothing can be taken for granted.

Comment: @ScotM x and y are items being counted, sorry. An example is: "a combined total of 100 sticks and rocks". This could be: 0 sticks and 100 rocks, 50 sticks and 50 rocks, 100 sticks and 0 rocks, or anything as long as the sum is 100.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, it seems that both of the OP options leave plenty of ambiguity. I find Brian's answer to be adequate, but not satisfying. Something along the lines of ***"any combination of x and y totaling 100"*** seems to strike closer to the point with less ambiguity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it might be 100 of X (sticks) and no y (rocks), or no x (sticks) and 100 y (rocks), or any combination that adds up to 100, I would say this is one of a few occasions where the best conjunction would be "and/or"

- A combined total of 100 sticks and/or rocks.

But of the two examples you gave, I would say that the version with "and" is more comprehensible.
It's hard to imagine a "combined" total as arising from any things connected by "or". One tends to think of "100 sticks or 100 rocks" but not to think of a mixture.  The  "combined" seems to contradict this, but it's still confusing.

The problem is that in ordinary English, "or" is ambiguous.  It might mean "x or y but NOT both" (logicians call this EXCLUSIVE OR), but it often is used to mean "x or y OR both" (logicians call this INCLUSIVE OR). If you fail to clarify which kind of OR you mean, words such as "total" and "combined" do not completely remove the ambiguity.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This does answer the specific question but not the broader question: is it situational? Is there a time where you would want to use one or the other?

Comment: I think that in all sutuations that fit the pattern you described, the "and" version would be better than the " or" version, but the "and/or version would be better than either of them.  If you would like to propose a different situation or a different construction, I would be glad to comment on that as well.